# Rasterizing GeoJSON in C# to generate TIFF file

Tags: gdal, geojson, c#

I'm trying to use gdal and C# to rasterize a GeoJSON object to TIFF.  I can get my code to compile and run but the image is coming up blank.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I need to specify the thickness of the line.  Here is my code.

```
using MaxRev.Gdal.Core;
using System;

using OSGeo.GDAL;
using OSGeo.OSR;

namespace Poc
{
    class Hello
    {
        public static void usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage: gdalinfo {GDAL dataset name}");
            System.Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
        // static void Main(string[] args)
        // {
        //     System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        //     // call it once, before using GDAL
        //     // this will initialize all GDAL drivers and set PROJ6 shared library paths
        //     GdalBase.ConfigureAll();
        //     Gdal.AllRegister();

        // }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (args.Length != 1) usage();

            Console.WriteLine("Starting ");

            try
            {
                Rasterize(args[0], "output.tif", 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Application error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        public static void Rasterize(string inputFeature, string outRaster, int cellSize)
        {
            // Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster  
            int rasterCellSize = cellSize;
            const double noDataValue = -9999;
            string outputRasterFile = outRaster;
            //Register the vector drivers  
            OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();
            //Reading the vector data  
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize1");
            var result = Gdal.GetConfigOption("PROJ_LIB", "DONT KNOW");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            OSGeo.OGR.DataSource dataSource = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.Open(inputFeature, 0);
            OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = dataSource.GetLayerByIndex(0);
            OSGeo.OGR.Envelope envelope = new OSGeo.OGR.Envelope();
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize1.5");
            Console.WriteLine(layer);
            layer.GetExtent(envelope, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Extent: " + envelope.MaxX + " " + envelope.MinX + " " + envelope.MaxY + " " + envelope.MinY);
            //Compute the out raster cell resolutions  
            double x_res = ((envelope.MaxX - envelope.MinX) / rasterCellSize);
            double y_res = ((envelope.MaxY - envelope.MinY) / rasterCellSize);

            Console.WriteLine("X resolution: " + x_res);
            Console.WriteLine("X resolution: " + y_res);
            //Register the raster drivers  
            Gdal.AllRegister();
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize2");
            //Check if output raster exists & delete (optional)  
            if (File.Exists(outputRasterFile))
            {
                File.Delete(outputRasterFile);
            }
            //Create new tiff   
            OSGeo.GDAL.Driver outputDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize2.4");
            Dataset outputDataset = outputDriver.Create(outputRasterFile, 100, 100, 1, DataType.GDT_Float64, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize2.8");
            //Extrac srs from input feature   
            string inputShapeSrs;
            OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference spatialRefrence = layer.GetSpatialRef();
            spatialRefrence.ExportToWkt(out inputShapeSrs, null);
            //Assign input feature srs to outpur raster  
            outputDataset.SetProjection(inputShapeSrs);
            //Geotransform  
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize3" + inputShapeSrs);
            double[] argin = new double[] { envelope.MinX, rasterCellSize, 0, envelope.MaxY, 0, -rasterCellSize };
            outputDataset.SetGeoTransform(argin);
            //Set no data  
            Band band = outputDataset.GetRasterBand(1);
            band.SetNoDataValue(noDataValue);
            //close tiff  
            outputDataset.FlushCache();
            outputDataset.Dispose();
            //Feature to raster rasterize layer options  
            //No of bands (1)  
            int[] bandlist = new int[] { 1 };
            //Values to be burn on raster (10.0)  
            double[] burnValues = new double[] { 10.0 };
            Dataset myDataset = Gdal.Open(outputRasterFile, Access.GA_Update);
            //additional options  
            Console.WriteLine("Rasterize4");
            string[] rasterizeOptions;
            //rasterizeOptions = new string[] { "ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", "ATTRIBUTE=" + fieldName }; //To set all touched pixels into raster pixel  
            rasterizeOptions = new string[] { "ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE" };
            //Rasterize layer  
            //Gdal.RasterizeLayer(myDataset, 1, bandlist, layer, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 1, burnValues, null, null, null); // To burn the given burn values instead of feature attributes  
            Gdal.RasterizeLayer(myDataset, 1, bandlist, layer, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 1, burnValues, rasterizeOptions, new Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate(ProgressFunc), "Raster conversion");
        }
        private static int ProgressFunc(double complete, IntPtr message, IntPtr data)
        {
            Console.Write("Processing ... " + complete * 100 + "% Completed.");
            if (message != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.Write(" Message:" + System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(message));
            }
            if (data != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.Write(" Data:" + System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(data));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return 1;
        }
        private static string GDALInfoGetPosition(Dataset ds, double x, double y)
        {
            double[] adfGeoTransform = new double[6];
            double dfGeoX, dfGeoY;
            ds.GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);

            dfGeoX = adfGeoTransform[0] + adfGeoTransform[1] * x + adfGeoTransform[2] * y;
            dfGeoY = adfGeoTransform[3] + adfGeoTransform[4] * x + adfGeoTransform[5] * y;

            return dfGeoX.ToString() + ", " + dfGeoY.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the GeoJSON looks like this.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-84.45, 33.35],
          [-84.55, 33.45],
          [-84.5, 33.55]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
      }
    } 
] }
```

Comment: Compare your result with the output of the gdal_rasterize utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html. If there is a difference then you probably has some error in your code. Gdal_rasterize suits best for rasterizing polygons. There is no setting for line thickness in, except "all_touched". The line is always one pixel wide and a point gets rasterized into one pixel. Use other tools, like QGIS server or GeoServer if you want to get a nice cartographic presentation.

Comment: Thanks. We are trying to generate a map image with a line drawn on it representing a path.  We were doing this with mapserver but we are trying to eliminate that functionality now.  Do you have any other suggestions that we can do programatically.

Comment: I don't know anything about rendering libraries. All I know is that MapServer is using AGG in background. But maybe you could try a workaround and create a buffer for you linestring. Then you'll have a polygon to feed for gdal_rasterize. Browsers are good at rendering for example GeoJSON, maybe you can find something from that world.